# Bootstrap Button Hover issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I hover over a bootstrap button on my website it doesn't show the link in the bottom left corner in chrome. Am I missing something here? Here is the code I am currently using for the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn m-l-15 m-r-15" onclick="location.href='{$relative}/upload'">{translate c='menu.upload'}</button>
```

Comment: I think because a button is not a link.

Comment: Any idea what I would need to change to code to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `<a>` element with a role of button and style it to look like a button but using the same classes that you are currently using.

Only caveat to this would be that you should determine the correct element to use in your situation - for example - a link (a element) should navigate you to a new location or context - whilst a button should be used if it does something in the same location / context.

Also - if the bottonhad other functionality that navigating to the desired location - you will need to re-introduce the click handler and apply logic to perform that function.

```
<a 
  href="{$relative}/upload" 
  role="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn m-l-15 m-r-15"
>{translate c='menu.upload'}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the `margin-left` and `margin-right` from `m-l-15` and `m-r-15` to `ml-1` and `mr-1`. In bootstrap `ml` and `mr` class only take values from 1 to 5. It don't takes the values more than 5 in class. You have to give it to css.

Try This:

```
 <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn ml-5 mr-5" 
    href="{$relative}/upload">{translate c='menu.upload'}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your link as follows and it may solve your problem

```
<a href="your_link_here">         
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn ml-5 mr-5">
      {translate c='menu.upload'}
   </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with a link , and style it.
Have a visit to Bootstrap website and you will find Details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/reboot/#forms).